# How to mimic Apple Map's translating table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am making an app that returns venues (like restaurants) in a fashion similar to apple maps, i.e. a table view that is initially hidden mostly off screen and then moves up above other content when the table view's contents are to be displayed. 
This is what I've gotten so far:

[image]

You'll notice that when pulling the table view back down to reveal the map behind it, the table view does not move down in one fluid motion. In fact, when the table view reaches its "top," you'll notice that the scroll bar on the right side is visible but the view isn't moving. This is because, while recording, I'm dragging downward but the view takes a few moments to actually begin to translate downward. I'll explain why it has this sort of delay, but first compare this behavior to that of the Apple maps table view:
[image]

Notice the fluidity in the Apple maps table view's transition from translating the view itself to scrolling the scroll view. A translation upward of the view converts into a scrolling downward of the scroll view  (and vice versa) when the view's minY hits a certain point. This is all done throughout one upward swipe by the user.

Now I'll explain what I did to create my translating scroll view. The scroll view itself is a UITableViewController embedded in a container view on the map's view controller.
[image]

The view that holds the container view has a pan gesture recognizer. When the pan gesture recognizer's state is UIGestureRecognizerState.ended, i.e. the drag has ended, it checks the container view's minY in relation to a predetermined Y coordinate. If the minY is less than the predetermined Y coordinate, it will animate the container view to snap its minY to that Y coordinate. The case is the same if the minY is slightly greater than the predetermined Y coordinate, in this instance the container view will animate upward so its minY snaps to this predetermined Y coordinate.
[image]

Once the view has snapped into this position, the embedded UITableViewController's ".isScrollEnabled" property, which is initially set to false, is now set to true. When the embedded table view is now scroll enabled, a drag executed by the user will scroll the table view as opposed to translating the container view. To undo this, I've made it so that when the table view has reached the top of its scroll, its ".isScrollEnabled" property is set back to false. This means that any dragging motion by the user will translate the view as opposed to scrolling the table view. This does not create the fluidity in transition between scrolling and translating the way Apple maps does. The user would actually have to execute multiple drags on the area in order to transition from scrolling to translating; Apple maps is able to do this in one drag.
Here is the code I used within the container view's parent View controller to:

- Snap container view into place
- Change .isScrollEnabled property of embedded table view controller to true

  ```
  @objc func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

  let resultView = self.resultView
  let translation = sender.translation(in: view)

  switch sender.state {
  case .began, .changed:

      resultView?.center = CGPoint(x: (resultView?.center.x)!, y: (resultView?.center.y)! + translation.y)
      sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)

      if (resultView?.frame.minY)! <= self.view.frame.height - self.searchView.frame.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom && self.resultView.frame.height >= (self.searchView.frame.height + self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom) {
          resultView?.frame.size.height -= translation.y
      }

  case .ended:
      if (resultView?.frame.minY)! > self.view.frame.height * 0.40 {

          self.resultTableViewController?.tableView.isScrollEnabled = false

      } else {

          self.resultTableViewController?.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true

      }

      if (resultView?.frame.minY)! <= view.frame.height * 0.40 {

          let difference =  (resultView?.frame.minY)! - (view.frame.height * 0.05)

          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
              resultView?.center = CGPoint(x: (resultView?.center.x)!, y: (resultView?.center.y)! - difference)
              resultView?.frame.size.height += difference
              self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
          }
          dismissed = false
      } else if (resultView?.frame.minY)! >= view.frame.height * 0.75 {
          let difference = (view.frame.height - dismissResultButton.frame.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom) - (resultView?.frame.minY)!

          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
              resultView?.center = CGPoint(x: (resultView?.center.x)!, y: (resultView?.center.y)! + difference)
              self.resultView.frame.size.height = self.searchView.frame.size.height + self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
              self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
          })
          dismissed = true
      } else if (resultView?.frame.minY)! >= view.frame.height * 0.40 {
          let difference = mapView.frame.height - (resultView?.frame.minY)!

          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
              resultView?.center = CGPoint(x: (resultView?.center.x)!, y: (resultView?.center.y)! + difference)
              self.resultView.frame.size.height = self.searchView.frame.size.height + self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
              self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
          }
          dismissed = false
      }

      sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
  default:
      break
  }

  }
  ```

And now, within the UITableViewController:

Ensures that the scroll view only bounces when at the bottom of the scroll (it should lock and then convert to a container translation when reaching the top)

Change .isScrollEnabled back to false and allow container view translation on drag

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.bounces = (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0)
}

override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview!)
    if translation.y > 0 {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0 {
            tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

This is the best I could come up with to try and replicate this behavior by the Apple maps table view. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S. heres the github to the project if you'd like to break it down more: https://github.com/ChopinDavid/What2Do

Comment: You can look at: PullUpController https://github.com/MarioIannotta/PullUpController by @MarioIannotta.

Comment: I also need solution for this

Comment: @FE_Tech UISheetPresentationController

Comment: @HangarRash how this will solve the above problem?

Comment: @FE_Tech It's what's used in the Maps app (and many others) to show a partial-screen view controller (the interactive screen that can be pulled up or down partially covering the underlying screen).